# Replace the result of a regex match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I read lots of linked questions but I cant  find what I need. Here is my problem :

```
inputStr = "<a b c> <c f a> <h a d>";
```

And i would like to grab only the first element of each `<...>`

```
OutputStr = "a c h";
```

I tried something like

```
mychar.replace(/<[a-z](.*)>/g, '$1');
```

but the `$1` only gives me `<a b c>`

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 7):

Your regular expression is wrong. You need to match the first letter but not everything that goes after it. And don't forget about a lazy match `?` in the current case:

```
"<a b c> <c f a> <h a d>".replace(/<([a-z]).*?>/g, "$1");  // "a c h"
```

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: he'll have to ask again once he has a changed problem :) explanation would be nice

Comment: @MichelFeldheim So you think my answer is wrong? ;) If the answer does not provide an explanation, then we suppose the OP will find out how it works by himself. At least I always do so, if I get a solution. Moreover, I don't think it is worth rewriting [MDN article about regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @Paul: [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) explains lazy matching very well

Answer (score 1):

```
inputStr = "<a b c> <c f a> <h a d>";

OutputStr = inputStr.replace(/<([a-z]).*?>/g, "$1");
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add much to the previous one.